Are the groups $\mathbb{{Z}_2}\times\mathbb{{Z}_{12}}$ and $\mathbb{{Z}_4}\times\mathbb{{Z}_6}$ isomorphic?Why?
Basically,I know what isomorphism is and about the direct products of groups. But I couldn't able to understand how to tell that two direct product groups are isomorphic to each other even though I know "Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups". The normal procedure seems to difficult if the order is large,so how do I check whether two direct product groups are isomorphic and how?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The theorem on finitely generated abelian groups tells you how to answer this question by factoring the numbers 2,12, 4 and 6.

Yes but the gcd(2,12)=2=gcd(4,6), so we can't split the given direct products further right? So how to apply the theorem?

You don't need anything nearly as advanced as the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups in order to answer this question. Just use the Chinese remainder theorem.

$12=3\times 4$, so $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\cong\mathbb{Z}3\times\mathbb{Z}4$; so $\mathbb{Z}{2}\times \mathbb{Z}{12} \cong Z_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$. What about the other group?

This has been answered on the web, see here, for example. Or this homework solution, page $3$. The idea is just $6=2\cdot 3$ and $12=3\cdot 4$ with coprime factors.

If you want an explicit isomorphism, you can map $C_2 \times C_{12} \to C_4 \times C_6$ by $(m,n) \mapsto (2m+n, 3m+n)$, with inverse $C_4 \times C_6 \to C_2 \times C_{12}, (m,n) \mapsto (n-m, 3m-2n)$.  Of course, the other more conceptual approaches that others have given here are more useful in figuring out which products of cyclic groups are isomorphic in the first place.

Abelian groups are kind of conquered territory,  what with the structure theorem and all. If you know some category theory you can maybe even handle non-finitely generated ones.  But i digress.
We already have these written as products of cyclic groups.
Abelian groups happen to be modules,  and to answer this question,  it suffices to find invariant factors, which in turn can be gotten from elementary divisors.
Here the latter are 2,3,4 and 4,2,3 (just factor as much as possible,  using CRT).
Actually we can stop there.  The elementary divisors are the same,  the order doesn't matter.
They're isomorphic.
